# How to download File datatype(dataverse) field's Data through the canvas app?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, powerapps, dynamics-365, power-platform

A file field has been added to a custom entity that stores excel and pdfs. Now I want to download the file field's Data Through a canvas app. For that, I try with gallery and Form to get data from that Custom entity but was unable to download it. It shows an error "Couldn't download the File".
[Image that shows error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qobcA.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I believe you will have to call Dynamics API to download file content and then process it so that it saves/downloads as your required type. Here are some links for Ref.
https://debajmecrm.com/retrieve-contents-of-file-data-type-field-in-dynamics-365-cds-using-javascript-client-code/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/file-attributes#retrieve-file-data

Comment: did you managed to get this solved? did the above comment helped?